# Using LINQ for quering in a big database take so much time

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm using LINQ for preparing some data in my controller and sending them to view.
My connection provided by EF6 code first migration with sql server
So in the controller and with a LINQ expression , the model of database map to proper view model as follow:

```
        var temp = db.points.ToList().Select(pnt => new MapPointsModel()
        {
            pointId = pnt.pointId,
            name = pnt.name,
            positionX = pnt.positionX,
            positionY = pnt.positionY,
            road = pnt.road.id,
            order = pnt.order,
            signalState = pnt.signalState,
            powerState = pnt.powerState,
            videoState = pnt.videoState,
            cameraState = pnt.cameraState,
            hourTraffic = new int[]{
                pnt.crossings.Where(c => DateTime.Compare(c.dateTime, lastHour) >= 0 ).Where(c => c.line == 1).Count(),
                pnt.crossings.Where(c => DateTime.Compare(c.dateTime, lastHour) >= 0 ).Where(c => c.line == 2).Count(),
                pnt.crossings.Where(c => DateTime.Compare(c.dateTime, lastHour) >= 0 ).Where(c => c.line == 3).Count()
            },
            dayTraffic = new int[]{
                pnt.crossings.Where(c => DateTime.Compare(c.dateTime, lastDay) >= 0 ).Where(c => c.line == 1).Count(),
                pnt.crossings.Where(c => DateTime.Compare(c.dateTime, lastDay) >= 0 ).Where(c => c.line == 2).Count(),
                pnt.crossings.Where(c => DateTime.Compare(c.dateTime, lastDay) >= 0 ).Where(c => c.line == 3).Count()
            },
            hourViolation = new int[] {
                pnt.crossings.Where(c => c.violation != null && DateTime.Compare(c.dateTime, lastHour) >= 0).Where(c => c.line == 1).Count(),
                pnt.crossings.Where(c => c.violation != null && DateTime.Compare(c.dateTime, lastHour) >= 0).Where(c => c.line == 2).Count(),
                pnt.crossings.Where(c => c.violation != null && DateTime.Compare(c.dateTime, lastHour) >= 0).Where(c => c.line == 3).Count()
            },
            dayViolation = new int[] {
                pnt.crossings.Where(c => c.violation != null && DateTime.Compare(c.dateTime, lastDay) >= 0).Where(c => c.line == 1).Count(),
                pnt.crossings.Where(c => c.violation != null && DateTime.Compare(c.dateTime, lastDay) >= 0).Where(c => c.line == 2).Count(),
                pnt.crossings.Where(c => c.violation != null && DateTime.Compare(c.dateTime, lastDay) >= 0).Where(c => c.line == 3).Count()
            },
            checkedViolations = pnt.crossings.Where(c => c.violation != null).Where(c => c.violation.deliberated == true).Count(),
            uncheckedViolations = pnt.crossings.Where(c => c.violation != null).Where(c => c.violation.deliberated == false).Count(),
            bandAvgSpeed = new int[] {
                pnt.crossings.Where(c => c.line == 1).Count() == 0 ? 0 : pnt.crossings.Where(c => c.line == 1).Sum(c => c.speed)/pnt.crossings.Where(c => c.line == 1).Count(),
                pnt.crossings.Where(c => c.line == 2).Count() == 0 ? 0 : pnt.crossings.Where(c => c.line == 2).Sum(c => c.speed)/pnt.crossings.Where(c => c.line == 2).Count(),
                pnt.crossings.Where(c => c.line == 3).Count() == 0 ? 0 : pnt.crossings.Where(c => c.line == 3).Sum(c => c.speed)/pnt.crossings.Where(c => c.line == 3).Count(),
            },
        });
        return temp.ToList();
```

this code works for 10000 records or lower, but in 500000 record or more there is no result and in all tests timeout accurse.

I'm looking for the reason of this problem

## UPDATE:

There is just 4 records in "points" table, the bigger one with more than 500000 records is "crossings" however I tried to solve the problem with removing `.toList()` from `db.points`, but it rises exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Argument types do not match
```

Comment: `db.points.ToList`() mean select * from points, without where clause

Comment: As everyone pointed out your initial 'ToList()' will be retrieving the whole table. Use 'IEnumerable' or 'IQueryable' and only at the very end convert to a list. Alternatively there is a brilliant little Micro ORM library in Nuget called 'Dapper'. It will allow you to query the db using pure SQL and is also lightning fast. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/

Comment: @Fredou  tnx for comment, plz review the updated question

Comment: @scgough tnx , plz review the updated question

Comment: Take a look at the generated SQL using SQL Profiler. Because you already enumerated your initial list, each `Count()` call will generate its own query, which means even with just 4 points, you're still running 68 separate queries, each against a large set of data. I'd bet the problem is with the individual queries, not the LINQ, meaning you might just need some indexes.

Comment: @JoeEnos That's a perfect guide , can you explain more about indexes?
or add an answer about it ??

Comment: By indexes, I mean indexes on the database tables themselves. SSMS can help with generating missing indexes if you look at the execution plan, but ideally you're going to want a database developer or DBA to look at the query, and look at the table, to analyze where an index may come in handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was Average !!!

Because average function runs 4 times over the all records, it takes about 7 seconds.

I changed the linq query and instead of requesting all data at once , the average section calculated in other request from server with OrderBy GroupBy tools. and then combined two lists that retrieve from server.

Beside, I removed .ToList() from points table (as folks suggested) and changed arrays constructions to simple variables (this caused error!).

This solution caused runtime take just about 1 second instead of 7 second with the same output :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this:

```
db.points.ToList()....
```

This retrieves *ALL* records in their entirety from the table into memory.  So, the more records you have, the longer this will take.  You need to create a query that returns only the records you need.

I'm not sure what you're planning to do with 500,000 records all at once.. do you only need a subset?  If so, then do something like this:

```
db.points.Select(....).Take(25) // or however many you need.
```

You're also doing numerous sub-selects and sub-counts, each of those are separate statements that get executed, so for those 500,000 you might actually have many millions of sub-queries.

Comment: @HamedHamedi - Chances are it's the Date comparison that is the problem.  Instead of using `DateTime.Compare()`, use `EntityFunctions.DiffDays()` or `EntityFunctions.DiffHours()`.  Also, combine your where clauses as this can have some effect with sub-selects.  So instead of Where(...).Where(...) do .Where(... && ...)

Comment: You mentioned an important point, "sub-selects and sub-counts executed separate" !!!
As you can see through the code, my purpose is to collecting some data about each points(here we have just 4 points) from the big table (crossings) and then pass the list of objects to view.
If this solution (sub-selects) is not good, how can I do the same in a better way(with minimum execution)???

Answer (score 0):

You are transforming it to a List at the beginning. This is taking up all the time. Try removing the ToList() from db.points.ToList().Select. This should solve your problem.

Until you convert it using a ToList, it still is a IQueryable and will not hit the database. The moment you do a ToList, it will query the database, fetch the results in memory and then process the records in memory.

Answer (score 0):

doing this

```
    var temp = db.points.ToList()....
```

bring the whole table to the client, so if you have a few meg / gig of data this can take a while depending on cpu / connection / memory

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `ToList()` from the code and change `var temp = db.points.AsNoTracking()` This will save your time .Also creating pre-generated views for your code first model  gives better performance.